# Which is faster? Using a custom Comparator class or lambda function

Tags: lambda, java-8, comparator, treemap

I am trying to create a sorted map in java (sorted in decreasing order of key). 
I tried

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((a,b)->(b-a));
```

Would it create any performance impact if I write a Comparator class for the same task?

Comment: first of all, `(a,b)->(b-a)` this is wrong; second it would be the same thing under the hood (almost), you will *never* feel the difference

Comment: b-a is not wrong because I wanted it to be sorted in decreasing order. My bad . I should have mentioned that.

Comment: `(a,b)->(b-a)` is broken, because the *difference* between `a` and `b` does not fit into the value type of `a` and `b`. In case of `Integer`, the maximum difference between two values is the difference between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is 2³²-1, or twice as much as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So your comparator is subject to overflow. A correct implementation would be `(a,b)->Integer.compare(b,a)` or `(a,b)->b.compareTo(a)`, which does the same as `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. The bottom line is, don’t try to be clever by implementing comparators via subtraction.

Comment: I used `b-a` because all my Integers were going to be positive and `b-a` is faster than  `compareTo()` method. Also this matters because I asked this question because I wanted to know the performance impact in a competitive coding scenario, in the first place. What I wanted was to implement a `TreeMap` given that the input size was in the range of `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000`

Comment: This comparator using the difference will work when all values are positive, but I doubt that you ever made a valid benchmark regarding your claim that `(a,b) -> (b-a)` was faster than `(a,b) -> Integer.compare(b,a)` or `(a,b) -> b.compareTo(a)`, resp. `Comparator.reverseOrder()`. But, of course, “competitive coding scenario” more than often implies invalid measuring anyway, so the higher initialization costs may matter. In that case, using an existing comparator like `Comparator.reverseOrder()` will win in most cases.

Comment: If you know all your keys are going to be positive integers, you might get a better performance doing something "interesting" or even trivial with an array. e.g. `int[]` for the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will never feel a difference between creating a class *explicitly* and when then runtime will create one for you, *implicitly* via the lambda expression.

What you might want to improve is the readability of your code, wouldn't this be much easier to understand?

```
new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```